# i can not get in varartionb in command line

Tags: python, django

in my e comerce project i want to create variations for the products and here is my entire code
model.py

```
from django.db import models
from catagory.models import catagory
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name     =  models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    slug        =  models.SlugField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    description =  models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    price       =  models.IntegerField()
    image       =  models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/Product')
    stock       =  models.IntegerField()
    is_available=  models.BooleanField(default=True)
    catagory    =  models.ForeignKey(catagory,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        
        return self.product_name

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('product_detial',args=[self.catagory.slug,self.slug])
class VariationManager(models.Manager):
    def colors(self):
        return super(VariationManager,self).filter(varation_category='color',is_active=True)
    def sizes(self):
        return super(VariationManager,self).filter(varation_category='size',is_active=True)
varation_category_choice =(
    ('color', 'color'),
    ('size', 'size'),

    )

class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    varation_category = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices= varation_category_choice)
    varation_value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active  = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    objects = VariationManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.varation_value
```

views .py

```
def add_cart(request,product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    #product_varation=[]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for item in request.POST:
            key = item
            value = request.POST[key]
            #print(key,value)
            try:
                varation = Variation.objects.get(varation_category__iexact=key,varation_value__iexact=value)
                print(varation)
            except:
                pass
.....
```

and when i tray to add new product it added successfully but it dose not print the variation in the command line i don't know why it is not working please help me?

Comment: i did not understand where you save the variation,

Comment: i want to just print the  variation in the command line